# Calculate the area of the masks (in pixels) in grey scale images with python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, computer-vision, mask

The following coins figure is a greyscale image with different masks (shown in different colors). Is there a way to calculate the area of these masks (in pixels) for each coin in greyscale images with python.

[image]

Labels for the coin masks

```
{"classes": [{"title": "coin1", "shape": "polygon", "color": "#BE5C3C", "geometry_config": {}}, {"title": "coin2", "shape": "polygon", "color": "#961D82", "geometry_config": {}}, {"title": "coin3", "shape": "polygon", "color": "#C1BB5C", "geometry_config": {}}, {"title": "coin4", "shape": "polygon", "color": "#D0021B", "geometry_config": {}}, {"title": "coin5", "shape": "polygon", "color": "#417505", "geometry_config": {}}], "tags": []}
```

Annotation for the coin masks

```
{"tags": [], "description": "", "objects": [{"description": "", "bitmap": null, "tags": [], "classTitle": "coin1", "points": {"exterior": [[59.0, 85.0], [65.0, 70.0], [76.0, 63.0], [89.0, 61.0], [105.0, 63.0], [116.0, 78.0], [118.0, 98.0], [103.0, 117.0], [80.0, 118.0], [61.0, 103.0]], "interior": []}}, {"description": "", "bitmap": null, "tags": [], "classTitle": "coin2", "points": {"exterior": [[103.0, 43.0], [104.0, 28.0], [118.0, 17.0], [136.0, 16.0], [151.0, 22.0], [161.0, 34.0], [159.0, 53.0], [150.0, 68.0], [127.0, 73.0], [109.0, 62.0], [105.0, 54.0]], "interior": []}}, {"description": "", "bitmap": null, "tags": [], "classTitle": "coin3", "points": {"exterior": [[112.0, 143.0], [121.0, 129.0], [148.0, 124.0], [165.0, 141.0], [166.0, 160.0], [159.0, 175.0], [138.0, 184.0], [119.0, 174.0], [112.0, 161.0]], "interior": []}}, {"description": "", "bitmap": null, "tags": [], "classTitle": "coin4", "points": {"exterior": [[44.0, 137.0], [69.0, 134.0], [81.0, 152.0], [80.0, 171.0], [64.0, 181.0], [46.0, 178.0], [37.0, 168.0], [33.0, 151.0]], "interior": []}}, {"description": "", "bitmap": null, "tags": [], "classTitle": "coin5", "points": {"exterior": [[183.0, 117.0], [189.0, 100.0], [201.0, 93.0], [220.0, 98.0], [226.0, 111.0], [223.0, 126.0], [211.0, 136.0], [194.0, 135.0]], "interior": []}}], "size": {"height": 206, "width": 244}}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a method using OpenCV. We Otsu's threshold to obtain a binary image which leaves us with the desired foreground objects in white and the background is black. From here we use `cv2.countNonZero()` which returns the number of white pixels on the mask

---

[image]

To find the number of white pixels

```
pixels = cv2.countNonZero(thresh) # OR
# pixels = len(np.column_stack(np.where(thresh > 0)))
```

> pixels 198580

We could also calculate the pixel to total image area percent ratio

```
image_area = image.shape[0] * image.shape[1]
area_ratio = (pixels / image_area) * 100
```

> area ratio 24.43351838727459

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
pixels = cv2.countNonZero(thresh)
# pixels = len(np.column_stack(np.where(thresh > 0)))

image_area = image.shape[0] * image.shape[1]
area_ratio = (pixels / image_area) * 100

print('pixels', pixels)
print('area ratio', area_ratio)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

If you wanted to get individual coin pixel areas then you can iterate through each contour. The total area should be the same

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
total = 0

for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, [c], [255,255,255])
    mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    pixels = cv2.countNonZero(mask)
    total += pixels
    cv2.putText(image, '{}'.format(pixels), (x,y - 15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (255,255,255), 2)

print(total)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thank you. But does it give the pixel info for each coin?

Comment: What do you mean by pixel info?

Comment: I mean the area for coin1, coin2 .....coin5. I guess you need .json file that has mask labels? If yes, I just updated the question with the labels info.

Comment: The mask labels are unnecessary, you can iterate through each contour then find each individual coin area

Comment: Is it possible to save these pixel values in a file corresponding to their labels? something like `coin1 46728, coin2  47968 ....`

Comment: You would have to match the coin label with it's contour then write this information into a text file. I'm not sure how to you be able to match it. It may be better to open another question

Answer (score 0):

The number of true pixels for each labeled region is an estimate of the area for each labeled region.

Comment: yes, but how could I get them especially when I have many images with many masks?